# Unix Stat command not working for a directory with 23 million files

Tags: unix, solaris, stat, inode

What could be max inode count for stat command to work. We are going to partition the directory and we need to determine the limit so that stat command will work. PLease provide us the max count for which stat will work

Comment: `stat --help` ends with the following lines, did you check them? GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/stat>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) stat invocation'

Comment: What filesystem type?  How is it mounted? It wouldn't be NFSv2, would it?  Where is your `stat` command located?  Did you compile it yourself?  Post the output of `which stat` and `file /full/path/to/stat`.  Also post the output of `ls -li` for files that `stat` fails on.